Google Play Key Upgrading Issue
I am seeking clarification regarding the signing keys for my application. The first build was signed using the Google Signing Key, and I have upgraded to my own signing key fews day ago.
Currently, users on versions below T are not affected by the new key (will install failed).
According to feedback from Google support, it can be solved by dual release (using both the old and new keys).
I am confused about how to create a bundle signed with the old key, given that the initial build was signed by Google.
Could  please provide guidance on how to resolve this signing key issue for versions below?
Have email to Google, as below reply:

Please note that it is expected that the Android T and above devices will not receive the new key since you have not released a new app bundle that is signed with the new key yet. The date of upgrade was on September 24th and your last release on production was on September 16th.
With regard to devices below Android T, kindly note that you will have to make a dual release. A dual release is a strategy used in the Play Console when you need to update your app's signing key. It involves uploading two versions of your app: one signed with the old key and the other signed with the new key. This ensures that users with older devices can still receive updates without any issues. However, devices Android T and below will still ignore the new key.

